# combine tokens that match one regex sequence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using regexner module from Stanford NLP to find some custom entities consisting from multiple tokens. However, when a sequence of tokens is matched, each token gets independent NER tag. For example, consider this mock up annotation:

```
          <token id="1">
            <word>123</word>
            <lemma>123</lemma>
            <NER>SOMENUMBER</NER>
          </token>
          <token id="2">
            <word>321</word>
            <lemma>321</lemma>
            <NER>SOMENUMBER</NER>
          </token>`
```

Suppose, that these tokens matched this line:

[0-3]{3} [0-3]{3}  SOMENUMBER

Is there efficient way using Stanford NLP library to combine such tokens into one token or indicate that they came from one regex sequence?

Comment: You need to somehow reparse the Stanford NLP XML output. Or you could have put an underscore between numbers before you feed the textfile into StanfordNLP tools.